# Fetch rows from postgres table which contains a specific id in jsonb[] column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have a details table with adeet column defined as jsonb[]

a sample value stored in adeet column is as below image

Sample data stored in DB :

[image]

I want to return the rows which satisfies `id=26088` i.e row `1` and `3`

I have tried array operations and json operations but it does'nt work as required. Any pointers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please prefer sharing text data as sample rather than images for your next questions. It will be easier to manipulate for the answering people, and can be directly seen without firewall problems in opposite to the images.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, yes will adhere to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the type of the column `adeet` is not of type `JSON`/`JSONB`, but maybe `VARCHAR` and we should fix the format so as to convert into a `JSONB` type. I used `replace()` and `r`/`ltrim()` funcitons for this conversion, and preferred to derive an array in order to use `jsonb_array_elements()` function :

```
WITH t(jobid,adeet) AS
(
 SELECT jobid, replace(replace(replace(adeet,'\',''),'"{','{'),'}"','}')   
   FROM tab 
), t2 AS
(
SELECT jobid, ('['||rtrim(ltrim(adeet,'{'), '}')||']')::jsonb as adeet 
  FROM t
)
SELECT t.*
  FROM t2 t
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(adeet) j
 WHERE (j.value ->> 'id')::int = 26088
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=691fff4626fc54afd4a8979f38178a25)</kbd>

Comment: Barbaros, Thank you for the query. 
The table is of an node.js app. In the model definition adeet column is data type jsonb[ ], and in postgres the type is ARRAY & knex.js is employed for DB stuff. So it is not of varchar type.

if i run **to_json(adeet)** I see the output as 

[{"id": 26088, "name": "abcd", "xy": null, "catName": "full time", "category": 1},
{"id": 35035, "name": "efgh", "xy": "Y", "catName": "part time", "category": 1},
{"id": 5039, "name": "ijklm", "xy": null, "catName": "full time", "category": 3}]

please suggest an simpler query for this format

Comment: you're welcome @user13739109 . The same logic works again : [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=28c75e7a2102b7e2924c25248e7a9283)

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine JSONB's `<@` operator with the generic-array ANY construct.

```
select * from foobar where '{"id":26088}' <@ ANY (adeet);
```